# Incorrect results when dereferencing boost::optional directly from a return value

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost

This problem occurs for me on `GCC 4.4.7`, specifically `g++ 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)`. I've tried it under both `clang 3.8` and `GCC 4.8.4` and do not have the same problem. Boost version is `boost 1.55`. The minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct baz
{
    boost::optional<int> x;

    boost::optional<int> foo()
    {
        //If x is a local variable, the correct result is printed in main.
        x = 25;
        return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    baz b{{}};

    int t = 9999;
    if (b.foo()) {
        std::cout << "optional has value\n"; //Prints "optional has value" as expected
    }
    std::cout << b.foo().is_initialized() << "\n"; //Prints 1 as expected
    t = *(b.foo());

    std::cout << "t: " << t << "\n";    //Prints 0, expected 25
    std::cout << *b.foo() << "\n";      //Prints 0, expected 25
    std::cout << b.foo().get() << "\n"; //Prints 0, expected 25
    //For all of the above, minor code changes lead to
    //seemingly random differences in the results that are printed.
    //For example:
    //If this is uncommented, '25' is printed everywhere above, as expected:
    //std::cout << b.foo().get_ptr() << "\n";
}
```

This is compiled as `g++ example.cpp -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o bot` (note that it also fails under `-O3`, but not under `O0` or `O1`).

Is it possible this is caused by a strict aliasing issue? Or is there something else going on here I'm missing?

Edit:

A [runnable example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1kqJx0sc7puzorWn) on Wandbox.

Comment: Why are you using `unique_ptr`? Is it relevant to the problem? Does it work without it?

Comment: @juanchopanza This was distilled from a problem in a much larger program, so I was using a similar structure for the example. It doesn't work when not using `unique_ptr` though, no.

Comment: So remove it and get closer to a [mcve]?

Comment: I can't reproduce either version with clang on mac osx, boost 1.59.0 from macports.

Comment: Given that this issue appears to be specific to GCC 4.4, my guess is that is bug/limitation in boost that is a result of the pre-standard support for rvalue references present in GCC 4.4. I will do a more complete investigation and post an answer in a few hours if noone else comes along.

Comment: I've edited the question with a simpler version of some code that still demonstrates the problem. I wasn't able to figure out what the problem is caused by. It certainly could be some sort of compiler bug related to strict aliasing (`boost::optional` violates strict aliasing, but uses `__attribute__((__may_alias__))` to make the violation 'safe' (it is also possible that `boost` is using this attribute in a way that is not correct for GCC 4.4)). It is hard to test this, as the behavior is inconsistent.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to a newer version of GCC, or if that isn't possible, I would recommend subjecting your usage of `optional` to very thorough tests.

Comment: @Mankarse Thanks for the simplified example. Unfortunately upgrading to a newer gcc is unlikely to happen for a while; I will certainly be very careful using `optional` with it from now on.